# Can the Stealth Cruiser purchase shields?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Can the Stealth Cruiser ever purchase or otherwise obtain shields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**. You can find them being sold in stores along with other systems (Drone Control, Teleporter, etc), for the cost of 150 scrap.

I'm not aware of them being available by any other method.